# How to fix value error : invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, user-interface, calculator

It shows an error :

```
value error : invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

This code is a gui calculator I made it without an equal sign so I don't know where does the error come from (it's not showing the gui when I open it ).

I was learning tkinter tutorial on YouTube , in the tutorial he made a gui calculator with just adding button  so I decided to add all the signs, so it ended here asking for help

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
e = Entry(root , width=35)
e.grid(row=0 , column=0 , columnspan= 3, padx = 10 , pady = 10)


def button_add(number):
    current = e.get()
    e.delete(0 , END)
    e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))

first_number = e.get()

int(first_number)

def button_clear():
    e.delete(0 , END)

def adding_button():
    e.delete(0, END)
    sec_num = e.get()
    int(sec_num)
    e.delete(0 , END)
    e.insert(first_number  + sec_num)


def substract():
    e.delete(0 , END)
    first_num_sub = e.get()
    int(first_num_sub)
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(first_number - first_num_sub)

def dividing():
    e.delete(0, END)
    div_num = e.get()
    int(div_num)
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(first_number / div_num)

def multiply():
    mult_num = e.get()
    int(mult_num)
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(first_number * mult_num)

button1 = Button(root, text='1', padx=40 , pady=20,command= lambda    :button_add(1)).grid(row=1 ,column=0)
button2 = Button(root, text='2', padx=40 , pady=20,command= lambda :button_add(2)).grid(row=1 ,column=1)
button3 = Button(root, text='3', padx=40 , pady=20,command= lambda :button_add(3)).grid(row=1 ,column=2)
button4 = Button(root, text='4', padx=40 , pady=20,command= lambda :button_add(4)).grid(row=2 ,column=0)
button5 = Button(root, text='5', padx=40 , pady=20,command= lambda :button_add(5)).grid(row=2 ,column=1)
button6 = Button(root, text='6', padx=40 , pady=20,command= lambda :button_add(6)).grid(row=2 ,column=2)
button7 = Button(root, text='7', padx=40 , pady=20,command= lambda :button_add(7)).grid(row=3 ,column=0)
button8 = Button(root, text='8', padx=40 , pady=20,command= lambda :button_add(8)).grid(row=3 ,column=1)
button9 = Button(root, text='9', padx=40 , pady=20,command= lambda :button_add(9)).grid(row=3 ,column=2)
button0 = Button(root, text='0', padx=40 , pady=20,command= lambda :button_add(0)).grid(row=4 ,column=0)
clear_button = Button(root, text='clear', padx=80 , pady=20, command=lambda : button_clear()).grid(row=4 , column=1, columnspan=2)
add_button = Button(root, text= '+', padx=40 , pady=20, command=adding_button).grid(row=5 ,column=0)
sub_button= Button(root, text='-', padx=40 , pady= 20,command=substract).grid(row=6, column=0)
div_button = Button(root, text='/', padx=40 , pady=20, command=dividing).grid(row=6, column=1)
mult_button = Button(root, text='*', padx=40, pady=20, command=multiply).grid(row=6, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: *Where* does it report this error occurred, and what input(s) did you provide to generate the error?

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: Write less code at a time. Make each individual part work first.

Answer (score 1):

```
e.delete(0, END)
sec_num = e.get()
int(sec_num)
```

If you delete the text from the `e` text entry, then of course you `get` an empty string into `sec_num`, and an empty string cannot be converted to integer.

Similarly,

```
first_number = e.get()

int(first_number)
```

You try to do this outside of any functions, while the UI is still being set up; this is before the user has any chance to type in the `first_number`, so of course there is no text available to convert to the integer.

Please also note that simply writing `int(sec_num)` by itself *does not do anything useful*; in particular, it does **not** cause `sec_num` to become an integer. It only *computes* the integer value; you still need to do something with the result. It is just like how `value + 1` will not change `value`.